# How do I view the Asp.Net MVC page I uploaded to the FTP server?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, web, ftp

I created my project under the framework of Asp.Net MVC and uploaded it to FTP Server, but the file directories I viewed on the site were. Later, in my research, I saw that the server searched for public_html / index.html and started executing from there. However, since my project is in MVC structure, my index file is at Views / Home / index.cshtml and it works when my project is executed from here. Where can I change public_html / index.html or otherwise solve this problem?

Comment: ftp and hosting a Asp.Net MVC site have little to do with each other. I assume you are trying to host your site. Are you sure the hosting site supports MVC sites. FTP can be used to put the files on the server, but the server need to support it.

Comment: Then how can I publish my mvc project? I'm trying to upload to the site through the visual studio-publish-FTP

Comment: We can't tell you if your server supports Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: @Amy how i can understand server support MVC? Let's say server support MVC, how i update to ftp server for porperly work the site? I saw the Domain - Document Root - public_html in cPanel, but i don't change the root.

Comment: Usually it's easier to download a `Web Deploy Publishing Settings` file that you load in Visual Studio to deploy with one-click. I'm not sure cPanel supports .NET Framework apps.

Comment: the other have given gd advice, unfortunately we can not tell you if your hosting server support MVC .Net Framework. the they offer the web deploy publish this is usually and easier option. First check that the hosting company/server.. support it.